# The Navigation Bar items expands over 1 row it changes to ... as drop down

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap in building the navigation bar.
I have reviewed the bootstrap content but cant find a spot in navigation when content is larger then 1 row and items on right turn into ...

```
<header class="navbar navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

It displays:

(Edge Screen) Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4 Item 5 (Edge Screen)

(Edge Screen) Item 6

What I am looking for is:

(Edge Screen) Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4 ... (Edge Screen)

With the ... being a drop down showing Item 5 and Item 6.

When it gets to small screen, its a drop down menu.

---

When ever a nav item reaches the right side, have it thrown into a drop down menu.

For example, my screen see's this page as width 1903 , but if I make my screen a little smaller: 1841, if the nav item hits that wall, then it will drop down to the next level causing the rest of the page to be thrown off. Instead of having it drop to next level, I want it to go into a drop down menu instead.

Comment: hey i cant understand clearly what you are saying , please refer this fiddle like its working fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/7s95vkyw/

Comment: Bathri, If you look at this example, it show's 2 rows, but I only want 1 row, at the far right side, I want it to change from current item to ... and make it a drop down list. I made an example of what it should look like, could not get the bootstrap to work on this editor. https://jsfiddle.net/fcyrqpvw/1/

Comment: hey are u asking that after reaching the width of the screen it should change to drop down ?

Comment: Yes, I cant find anything that has an example of that.

Comment: In what kind of scenario you are expecting that. so that i can even help you with some other model which suits you.

Comment: When ever a nav item reaches the right side, have it thrown into a drop down menu.

For example, my screen see's this page as width 1903 , but if I make my screen a little smaller: 1841, if the nav item hits that wall, then it will drop down to the next level causing the rest of the page to be thrown off. Instead of having it drop to next level, I want it to go into a drop down menu instead.

Comment: Why cant u use drop down design for all the sizes?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h

This has a bootstrap nav bar.
When the screen reaches width: 767, it changes to down down nav bar.
But when its larger then 768, then it shows the Nav Bar, but if an item reaches the right side, it drops to the next level. That address does not have enough items to demonstrate that.

Comment: Just use media querys

Comment: How do I do a Media Query?

Comment: check my suggestion below bro it might help you to handle page response in  various sizes

Comment: I figured it out. No one answered my question.
I will post what I did later.

Answer (score 0):

To handle those kinds of cases **bootstrap use @media queries to have responce design** for all the screen sizes.i have sample media query below check it out it will help you for sure.

> change the size of the display then you will notice the css changes
>   automatically based on the size of the display.

you can alter the css as such you want in your page.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  body{
    background-color: brown;
  }
  .design {
    background-color: white;
  }
}



@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  body{
    background-color: green;
  }
  .design {
    background-color: red;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  body{
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .design {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  body{
    background-color: red;
  }
  .design {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="design">
This is a smaple div
</div>
```

Comment: That explains how to use @media screen, but that does not explain my issue.
I have that already, now what happens when max-width is greater than 1200px.

My screen width is 1903 on this page, but when I make it smaller by 25 or 50 or more, it could cause my navigation bar to jump down to the next level and that is not what I want.

Comment: @user8776656 For width 1903 change the max-width of the of media query and handle as you want.bootstrap nav bar is also handled by media query to be responsive. media query can have min-width,max-with and even several other attributes are avalible!!.I cant create css for you because i dont know the exact scenerio which u need. if you provide that i can make it for u.